# Cloud function getting stopped Parse.com in loop when calling from Arduino-yun

Tags: arduino-yun, code-review

I have created a cloud function using the Parse.com Javascript SDK and I am calling those functions from Arduino. Following is code for the `hello` function:

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
                response.success("This is hello function");         
}); //hello function Block
```

I am calling this function from the Arduino side using the following code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Bridge.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while (!Serial);

  Parse.begin("***zE0uUjQkMa7nj5D5BALvzegzfyVNSG22BD***", "***Ssggp5JgMFmSHfloewW5oixlM5ibt9LBSE***");
  //commented my keys with * here only

  // In this example, we associate this device with a pre-generated installation
  Parse.getInstallationId();
  Parse.startPushService();
}


void loop() {
  Serial.println("Start loop");
  demoBasic("meeting", 0);
}

void demoBasic(String functionname, int light) {
  char fnname[11];
  functionname.toCharArray(fnname, 11);

  Serial.print("In ");
  Serial.print(functionname);
  Serial.println(" Function");


  ParseCloudFunction cloudFunction;
  cloudFunction.setFunctionName(fnname);
  cloudFunction.add("light_sensor", light);
  cloudFunction.add("value", "Arduino Hello");//parameters

  ParseResponse response = cloudFunction.send();
  Serial.println(response.getJSONBody());
}
```

Problem is that I am getting response 8 times only. After that whole program flow gets blocked. What is the problem?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but I'd try a "delay" in loop after the call to demoBasic. I'd start with 100 ms. Maybe your code execute "too fast" then the js function gets blocked.

Comment: @fabrosell i tried doing that also but still there was problem.Can you suggest any othing thing which might solve issue.

Comment: If you have any working code which continuously able to push data to Parse.com,can you share that ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have any. Either way, it's a very strange behavior if function gets called just 8 times and no more...

Comment: At what point in the code does the program flow "get blocked"?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot, I really hate String, maybe that 8-times thing has to do with memory issues caused by it.

```
void loop() {

  char functionToCall[8] = "meeting";
  Serial.println("Start loop");
  demoBasicCharArray(functionToCall, 0);
}


void demoBasicCharArray(char *functionname, int light) {

  Serial.print("In ");
  for (byte i=0;i<sizeof(functionname);i++){
    Serial.print(functionname[i]);
  }
  Serial.println(" Function");

  ParseCloudFunction cloudFunction;
  cloudFunction.setFunctionName(functionname);
  cloudFunction.add("light_sensor", light);
  cloudFunction.add("value", "Arduino Hello");//parameters

  ParseResponse response = cloudFunction.send();
  Serial.println(response.getJSONBody());
}
```